Returning Varargs array cause exception only after 2nd level
I was reading Effective Java. There the author has mentioned that returning varargs array can cause Heap Pollution and can lead to ClassCastException. To support this he gave an example the modified version of which I am adding below.
public class Main {

    private static class A<T>{

    }

    static <T> T[] fun(T... arr){
        return arr;
    }

    static <T> T[] fun2(T a, T b){
        return fun(a, b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] z = fun("1", "2"); // no error
        String[] s = fun2("1","2"); // ClassCastExp
    }
}

The explanation for getting ClassCastException on String[] s = fun2("1","2"); is that due to type erasure fun2(T, T) will return Object[] which will not cast to String[] as Object is not subtype of String.
My question is that why am I not getting exception on line String[] z = fun("1", "2");. because fun(T...) is also returning Generic array which will be converted to Object[] array at runtime should throw ClassCastExcptn for the same reason above.
fun2(T, T) is internally using fun(T...).

The caller of a varargs method makes the array. In other words, this:
static <T> T[] fun(T... arr) {
  return arr;
}

Object x = fun("a", "b");

is syntax sugar1 for:
static Object[] fun(Object[] in) {
  return in;
}

Object x = fun(new String[] {"a", "b"});

The key takeaway is that the caller does the new String[2] part. It does new String[] instead of new Object[] because the array's component type is whatever T is resolved to, and that too (picking types for type vars) is done by the caller. This caller will pick String. Why not? Sure, Object also works, but as per the java lang spec, the most specific type that can safely be chosen, is chosen. String is more specific than Object, so, it's chosen. You can override it (Object x = MyClass.<Object>fun("a", "b")) - and if you do, you'll find that the component type is Object and not String.
Because it's the caller that's doing it, calling fun("a", "b") produces a string array. You can verify this; arrays are reified so you can ask an array its component type2.:
static <T> T[] fun(T... args) {
  return args;
}

Object x = fun("a", "b");
System.out.println(x.getClass().getComponentType());
// The above prints 'java.lang.String'.

The same principle applies in the fun2 case. However, look closely! The code that makes the array is the code that invokes the method with the varargs (so, fun) - and in the second case, it's the code in fun2 that does this, not your main method.
And, generics are figments of the compiler's imagination. Whatever information you can glean about the types at compile time (i.e. as you wrote it) is what goes. The definition of fun2 has absolutely no idea whatsoever that String is involved in any way. It's just T, with no bounds, so Object is all it knows, and thus, new Object[2] is what it makes. It dutifully passes this to fun which passes that array right back to fun2, and fun2 now returns it to code that attempts to assign this array to a variable of type String[] aaaaand ClassCastException because you can't do that.
We can check that too, without the ClassCastException:
static <T> T[] fun(T... args) {
  return args;
}

static <T> T[] fun(T a, T b) {
  return fun(a, b);
}

Object x = fun("a", "b");
System.out.println(x.getClass().getComponentType());
// The above prints 'java.lang.Object'.

Replace the Object x = part with String[] x =  and the compiler will allow it, but allows it by way of adding an invisible cast to String[]. At runtime, that cast will fail, so, ClassCastException.

[1] 'Syntax sugar' is a bit of a nebulous term. In general, it means: Is a different way to write a construct, and, this construct is implemented as if the compiler simply rewrites it to the other construct. In other words, it's like a macro. Here it means: Both snippets produce completely identical class files (other than irrelevancies such as the line number table).
[2]  In contrast to generics which aren't reified, so, you can't ask a list, for example, about its component type.
